# Jsoup, connected or not

Tags: android, jsoup, cas

I have to connect Jsoup to an url, which you can find in the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "debugger";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    downloadThread.start(); 

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {                     
    public void run() {                                    

        try {    
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Beginning");
            Response res = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://cas.scolastance.com/cas-auvergne/login?service=http://clg-cosne-d-allier.entauvergne.fr/sco/Modules/Accueil/Accueil.aspx")
                    .data("username", "myuser", "password", "mypass")
                    .data("submit", "SE CONNECTER") 
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();    
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,res.toString()); 

        } catch (IOException e) {                          
            e.printStackTrace();                           
        }                                                  
    }                                                      
};                                                         

}
```

The response is :

```
org.jsoup.helper.httpConnection$response@41577a10
```

Does that mean the connection is OK ?
I'm quite beginner in developping, sorry.
Thanks for answering

Comment: You need to look *inside* the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
res.statusCode();
```

You will get the status code of the response.

Look more in here: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html#statusCode()

You can try show the `res.body();` too.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both : res.body but the output is still the connection code source. And then, res.statuscode, which is 200, which means OK ? So, connected or not ?

Comment: I think so. 
200 OK: This is the most common HTTP status message. It indicates that the request was successful and the server was able to deliver on the request.
this is from http://webdesign.about.com/cs/http/p/http2xx.htm maybe that will be useful in the future

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Jsoup is not connected.
So I tried this way :

```
            //First connection, to read the key
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://cas.scolastance.com/cas-auvergne/login?service=http://clg-cosne-d-allier.entauvergne.fr/sco/Modules/Accueil/Accueil.aspx").get();
            String key ="";
            Element keyInput = doc.select("input[name=lt]").first();
            key = keyInput.attr("value");
            System.out.println("received value : " + key);

            //Second connection to post the data  
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Connecting ....");
            Response res = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://cas.scolastance.com/cas-auvergne/login?service=http://clg-cosne-d-allier.entauvergne.fr/sco/Modules/Accueil/Accueil.aspx")
                    .data("username", "myuser", "password", "mypass")

                    .data("lt", key) 
                    .data("_eventId", "submit") 
                    .data("submit", "SE CONNECTER") 
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute(); 

            int statusCode = res.statusCode();
            String body = res.body().toString();
            System.out.println("received code : " + statusCode);
            System.out.println("received body : " + body);
```

But the displayed body is still the "login" body and not the "connected" one.